# What float value makes sprintf_s() produce "1.#QO"?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, format, floating-point, printf

I have some (legacy embedded c) code which produces a .csv file by means of some `sprintf` calls. Occasionally I see values of `1.#QO`. I've tried reproducing those values with conditions which should give negative infinity, positive infinity and NaN but none of them appear to give me the magical `1.#QO` result. So what is it that produces that value?

...and yes, I know there's obviously something going wrong in the maths which produce that value, but understanding what it means would assist in the debugging effort.

**[Edit 1]** The actual line which does the conversion is:

```
sprintf_s(txt, CSV_HEADER_SIZE, "%.3f", value);
```

where:

```
#define CSV_HEADER_SIZE (100)
char txt[CSV_HEADER_SIZE];
```

I'm compiling with MS Visual Studio 2008.

**[Edit 2]** A bit more digging shows `0xFFFFFFFF` gives `-1.#QO`:

```
unsigned int i = 0xFFFFFFFF;
float* f = (float*)&i;
printf("%.3f", *f); // gives -1.#QO
```

..and looking at that in the Visual Studio debugger expands it to `-1.#QNAN00` so it looks like this is probably a Microsoft-specific representation of `NaN`?

Comment: What is the `sprintf()` line in question?

Comment: Can you identify one of the values that produced this result and format out the underlying float data in, say, hex? E.g., if it is a 4-byte float you could `printf("%X", value)`, or for an 8-byte you might be able to do `printf("%llX", value)` depending on the platform. This information would be helpful.

Comment: Could you identify the compiler (and, if applicable, the runtime)?  That particular `sprintf` output wasn't in the Standard last I looked, so it's probably very implementation-dependent.

Comment: I think 0xFFFFFFFF is the IEEE-754 standard representation of NaN--however the strange print out of that number seems Microsoft-specific.  Also, makes sense that you'd get this from dividing by zero. IEEE 754 NaN is talked about here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: also, see the note in the wikipedia article about qNaN (quiet, non-signalling NaN)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"-1.#QO" is "-1.#QNAN" after "rounding" for 3 places after the decimal.  The N rounds to an O as 'A' >= '5' and 'N' + 1 == 'O'.

This is similarly why your debugger shows "-1.#QNAN00", as it prints with 7 places and adds padding zeros to the end.

QNaN is [quiet NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Quiet_NaN).

Comment: That was the conclusion I reached too. Strange that it added the `O` on the end though.

Comment: @JonCage: MSVC uses trailing zeros to fill the required places, rather than handle QNAN differently from "regular"/non-NaN values.  Default places after the decimal is 6, so combine "%f" with a NaN (as in your answer) and remember strlen("#QNAN") is 5... :)

Comment: That last character is a letter (`O`) though rather than a zero (`0`). I think it's rounding the `N` up to an `O` because if you use `%.2f` you get `-1.#R` :-)

Comment: @JonCage: Ah, I crossed messages; in your answer you have "-1.#QNAN0".  Yes, indeed, it "rounds" the N to O here. That's why I put rounding in quotes, but I see it might not be obvious.  I'll expand the answer.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of fiddling around I can conclusively say that setting a 4-byte float to `0x7FFFFFFF` and passing it into `sprintf_s` with a format specifier of `%.3f` is what gave me `1.#QO`:

```
const int bufSize = 100;
char buf[bufSize];
unsigned int i;
float* f = (float*)&i;
int retval;

i = 0xFFFFFFFF;
retval = sprintf_s(buf, bufSize, "%.3f\n", *f);
printf("sprintf_s returned %d, converted val = %s", retval, buf); // == sprintf_s returned 7, converted val = -1.#QO
retval = sprintf_s(buf, bufSize, "%f\n", *f);
printf("sprintf_s returned %d, converted val = %s", retval, buf); // == sprintf_s returned 10, converted val = -1.#QNAN0

i = 0x7FFFFFFF;
retval = sprintf_s(buf, bufSize, "%.3f\n", *f);
printf("sprintf_s returned %d, converted val = %s", retval, buf); // == sprintf_s returned 6, converted val = 1.#QO
retval = sprintf_s(buf, bufSize, "%f\n", *f);
printf("sprintf_s returned %d, converted val = %s", retval, buf); // == sprintf_s returned 9, converted val = 1.#QNAN0
```

...it seems that the `%.3f` format specifier was cropping the NAN result so what should have been `1.#QNAN0` was being chopped down to `1.#QO`.

Answer (score 1):

A little googling points to a divide by 0 error.  Though I would expect something different if that were the case.  That said, it appears to be specific to MS/Visual C.

Comment: Bottom of this blog post: http://journal.joshburton.com/2008/01/1qo-value-of-doom.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you check whether sprintf_s() returned a failure?  If it does, you should not use the result.  Since the code doesn't look like you checked, I think you should do that checking.  In fact, if you don't test the result from one of the `*_s()` functions, you are headed for trouble.

Comment: From the documentation I've seen [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx] it's only if it's returning `<= 0` that there's a problem (an error or no characters written)? But since the value is being written out seemingly okay, I doubt that's where the problem lies. The actual code we're using is a little more involved. I just chopped it down to make it more concise (perhaps too much?). We do check return values in practice.

Comment: If you test the result at all, then you are probably OK. It was not clear from your 'snippet' that you checked the return value. I got '404 not found' from your link; but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx) worked.

Comment: Fair point and worth checking that I'd not missed that point :-)