# Why are the return values of these doubles -1.#IND?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, opencv

I have :

```
double score = cvMatchContourTrees( CT1, CT2, CV_CONTOUR_TREES_MATCH_I1, 0.0 );
        cout<<score<<endl;
```

There are values returned as -1.#IND. Other than that, the positive values are normal, like 1.34543.

Why does this happen? How do I solve it?

Comment: `#IND` is [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). You might want to read [this](http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html).

Comment: `cvMatchContourTrees` and OpenCV are complete red herrings in this question.

Comment: @Tomalak, how can you be sure? Is the question "What does -1.#IND mean?" or is it "How did cvMatchContourTrees return that value?"

Comment: @Mark: Fair point. I suppose it could be both.

Comment: See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/21/10395734.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/28/10397976.aspx

Answer (score 15):

As Frederic says, it's the result of a '[Not a Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)' being formatted by an application built with visual studio on windows. John D Cook has an [excellent reference](http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html):

> Windows displays a NaN as  -1.#IND ("IND" for "indeterminate") while Linux displays nan.
>
> ...
>
> In short, if you get 1.#INF or inf, look for overflow or division by zero. If you get 1.#IND or nan, look for illegal operations.

Watch out for truncations if you do any sort of formatting with your string; I've encountered [related issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939573/what-float-value-makes-sprintf-s-produce-1-qo) when handling these sorts of errors myself.

Comment: I'm not sure about `0/0` yielding `NaN`. I think it's like any other division by zero in that you'll get a floating-point exception from the OS.

Comment: @Tomalak: With Visual Studio, 0 / 0 throws an exception. 0.0 / 0.0 either returns NaN or throws an exception, you control that by a flag. The default is that it returns NaN.

Comment: @user763305: Yes, exactly. And that's not what the original quote said. My point is, beware the perils of Wikipedia...

Comment: Maybe.. ...or maybe it's in a library call and that library silently masks the exception but still spits out NaN as per the OPs question... ?

Answer (score 5):

```
std::cout << (0/0.f);
// Output: -1.#IND
```

It's [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Answer (score 3):

In my experience `-1.#IND` comes from imaginary numbers. So, doing `cout << sqrt(-1.);` should output `-1.#IND`