# C++ using 1 function for multiple varaibles. Only first run works

Tags: c++

Newish to C++ but been researching alot so please bear with me.

I've been trying to use 1 function to relate 8 global double variables [ mA mB ... mG  which ranges from values 1 to 10] to another double value.
I first obtain these 8 variables by obtaining the data from a csv file, throwing them to an array and then equating the set global variables. **This all works fine.** I cout the values correctly.

```
mA =10, mB=1 ,.... mG=2
```

However I need to use these variables to relate to another set value. So i Use:

```
double Function1(double Mvalue1)
{
    if (Mvalue1 == 1) { double value = 10; return value ; } 
    if (Mvalue1 == 2) { double value = 20; return value ; } 
    .... // cont to 10 only increasing value by 10
    if (Mvalue1 == 10) { double value = 110; return value ; }
}

void VarFunction()
{   
    mA2= Function1(mA); **//SHOULD output 110**
    cout << "Vaule A " << mA2 << endl;

    mB2= Function1(mB); **//SHOULD output 10**
    cout << "Vaule B " << mB2 << endl;
     ....//.... 8 times
    mG2 = Function1(mG); **//SHOULD output 20**
    cout << "Vaule G " << mG2 << endl;
}
int main()
{
   VarFunction()
   return 0;
}
```

So the output i get here is

```
Value A 110
Value B -1.#IND
.... 
Value G -1.#IND
```

Why isnt the next call of function1 with the next variable not working?

Comment: Perhaps this might give you some clues? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476177/why-the-return-value-of-double-is-1-ind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have `mA` set to 12, but `Function1` doesn't have a case for 12. So, I'm surprised you're even getting 110 printed for the first line. You aren't handling the case inside `Function1` where `Mvalue1` isn't one of the desired values, so this is the first thing to fix.

Also, assigning a number to a double and then returning it is unnecessarily complicated. A case statement would work well, assuming you really want to pass integers:

```
double Function1(int Mvalue1)
{
    switch(Mvalue1) {
        case 1: return 10;
        case 2: return 20;
        //...
        case 10: return 110; // are you sure you don't want 100?
        default: return -1; // handle the case here so that you always return a value.
    }
}
```

Of course, if you really just want 10 times your input, why not:

```
double Function1(double mValue1)
{
    return mValue1*10;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help eh... I tired to do the switch. I'm still getting the good output for the first variable mA BUT -1.#IND for the rest. I get the *10 thing but its ment to relate a set number to another.... IE Product mA relates to the ID 10 in my cvs file which i need to relate to the price 9.23, then Product  mB relates to the ID 1 which is 5.80. etc.

Comment: I suggest testing the code directly: `cout << "Vaule A " << Function1(20) << endl;` If this doesn't work, you need to copy and paste your *exact* code.

Comment: Ya my prob is that its course related in my grad schooling, I cant post the exact code. I'm no programing so i really thankful for ya.

Answer (score 0):

Not all paths in your function return a defined value, i.e. there's no `return` statement after all the conditionals.
The compiler is probably telling you that. If not - compile with higher warning level.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) container when building relationships like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<double, double> rel_t;

int main()
{
    rel_t mymap;
    // You can directly
    // std::map<double, double> mymap;


    mymap[1] = 10;
    mymap[2] = 20;
    mymap[10] = 110;

    std::cout << mymap[1] << std::endl;     // Prints 10
    std::cout << mymap[2] << std::endl;     // Prints 20
    std::cout << mymap[10] << std::endl;    // Prints 110

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This program seems to be working for me when I run it. However, I had to add declarations for `mA2`, `mB2`, and `mG2` in your `VarFunction()`. You're also missing a semicolon after your call to `VarFunction()` in `main()`.

I'd also suggest you return some default double in the function `double Function(double Mvalue1)`, just in case `Mvalue1` does not satisfy any of the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, `Function1()` should return a value in case all `if` statements are false!

If the numbers your are dealing with have no fractional digits, use `short`, `int`, `long` or any other integer type for the variables. Then you can use a `switch()`/`case` construct or keep on using the comparison operator `==`.

In case you must deal with floating point values, never use the `==` operator! When reading floating point values from text files (like CSV) or a database, a conversion from text to `float`/`double` is done. The result from such conversion can end in e.g. 9.999999999 or 10.000000001 instead of 10. And then the comparison with `==` is `false`!

To compare two double variables use a method like this:

```
bool dEqual( double dVal1, double dVal2, double dTolerance)
{
    if( fabs( dVar1 - dVar2) < dTolerance) {
        // dVar1 is nearly equal to dVar2
        return true;
    }

    // dVar1 is not equal to dVar2
    return false;
}
```

Then this comparison is true:

```
if( dEqual( 10.0, 9.999999998, 0.000001))
```

Apply a value for tolerance that meets the accuracy you need.